# Sikuli multiple window screen of same image

Tags: java, eclipse

Problem: Need to automate, multiple screens of same image. Input to each image is different. They have to run parallel.

What I did : I created plain java code inorder to automate one window using sikuli.

Solution needed: Need to handle multiple screens of same image with different input data.

```
Test(String name,String Password,Screen s){ s.type(name); s.type(Key.Enter); s.click(image1.sikuli); s.click(image2.sikuli);
```

in the above code name,password,screen values are from main class...I'm calling the function test from the main class ...I have different names and passwords now I need to open 25 window application and enter different set of names and passwords all to enter parallel and execute parallel

Comment: Could you post your code here?

Comment: Test(String name,String Password,Screen s){ s.type(name); s.type(Key.Enter); s.click(image1.sikuli); s.click(image2.sikuli);      in the above code name,password,screen values are from main class...I'm calling the function test from the main class ...I have different names and passwords now I need to open 25 window application and enter different set of names and passwords all to enter parallel and execute parallel